# Single slit of diffraction with increased width of slit

Tags: diffraction

**Question in brief** : Why increased width of slit makes single slit diffraction almost unobservable?

**Question in broad** : I was going through my textbook and found that diffraction cannot be observed if light is passed through a pin hole since width of a pin hole is way larger than the wavelength of the incident light. To clear out this confusion I took help from Fundamentals of Physics by Halliday and Resnick. At first I thiugh the intensity of fringes of same order change drastically due to the change of slit width. However noticed that the Intensity is basically dependent on phase difference not on slit width. Again I went through my textbook and though that the equation of phase difference might be a key equation in this case. I need a little bit of clarification in this case.

Phi=2(pie)*a*sin(theta)/lamda

Here phi is proportional to a*sin(theta). Now if we consider phi to be the phase difference of 1st order maxima then phi is constant. So increase in slit width will cause fringes to get narrower. Since dark fringes are always a bit thinner than the bright ones and its been narrowed due to the increment of a, it will gradually be unobservable if 'a 'is increased. So it would be quitw tough to differentiate between the the central maxima and 1st order maxima. Hence it looks like there is no diffraction.

Could this be the reason behind phenomenon about which  the question I have asked?

[image]

Comment: Because the Fourier transform of a narrow slit has much higher frequency components than a wide slit (and thus the range of perpendicular momentum transfers for a narrow slit is much larger).

Comment: I am not familiar with fourier transform